# Convert dynamic object to multi level JSON array based on Key Substring using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create multi level JSON array from flat dynamic object based on Key Substring

Sample dynamic object

```
{
  Honda_Bike: "white",
  Pulsar_Bike: "black",
  Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red",
  Hyundai_Car: "blue",
  Mercedes_Car: "grey",
  BMW_Car: "red"
}
```

Sample Json Multi - Level array

```
[{
  vehicle : {
    bike: {
      Honda_Bike: "white",
      Pulsar_Bike: "black",
      Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red"
    },
    car: {
      Hyundai_Car: "blue",
      Mercedes_Car: "grey",
      BMW_Car: "red"
    },
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the entries of the input object to check and categorize the items into your desired output format:

```js
const input = {
  Honda_Bike: "white",
  Pulsar_Bike: "black",
  Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red",
  Hyundai_Car: "blue",
  Mercedes_Car: "grey",
  BMW_Car: "red"
};
const output = [{ }];
output[0].vehicle = Object.entries(input).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  const vehicleName = key.match(/([^_]+)$/)[0];
  if (!a[vehicleName]) a[vehicleName] = {};
  a[vehicleName][key] = val;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of doing this using `Object.reduce`. First get the Object's own enumerable keys using `Object.keys` then use `Object.reduce`.

```js
let o = {
  Honda_Bike: "white",
  Pulsar_Bike: "black",
  Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red",
  Hyundai_Car: "blue",
  Mercedes_Car: "grey",
  BMW_Car: "red"
}
let keys = Object.keys(o);
let result = keys.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  let [type] = cv.split('_').reverse();
  acc[type] = acc[type] || {};
  acc[type][cv] = o[cv];
  return acc;
}, {});
result = [{
  vehicle: result
}];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why dv for the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys of the `data` object, split each key of the `data` object with respect to underscore `_` and then get the last splitted value to create a new key for the inner object. In each iteration check if this new key is created or not and based on that assign the value to this inner object.

```js
var data = {
    Honda_Bike: "white",
    Pulsar_Bike: "black",
    Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red",
    Hyundai_Car: "blue",
    Mercedes_Car: "grey",
    BMW_Car: "red"
  };

var vehicleObj = {};
//loop thorugh the data object keys
Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=>{
  //split the key and get the last splited value
  var splitArray = key.split('_');
  var newKey = splitArray[splitArray.length - 1];
  //create a new object based on the splited value
  if(vehicleObj[newKey]){
    vehicleObj[newKey][key] = data[key];
  } else {
    vehicleObj[newKey] = {};
    vehicleObj[newKey][key] = data[key];
  }
});
//create final output object
var res = [{
  'vehicle': vehicleObj
}];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to check all the objects and then match vehicleType which is last word of each key you. If matches then create new object and push related type vehicles into that. Below is working code snippet:

```js
let input = {
  Honda_Bike: "white",
  Pulsar_Bike: "black",
  Royal_Enfield_Bike: "red",
  Hyundai_Car: "blue",
  Mercedes_Car: "grey",
  BMW_Car: "red"
};

let output = [{}];
output[0].vehicle = Object.entries(input).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  let vehicleType = (key.match(/([^_]+)$/)[0]).toLowerCase();
  if (!a[vehicleType]) a[vehicleType] = {};
  a[vehicleType][key] = val;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```